# Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (None, 256) but got array with shape (16210, 4096)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I got an issue when trying to train my model in Keras 2.1.2
, Python 3.6.0, and a Tensorflow 1.3.0 Backend

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (None, 256) but got array with shape (16210, 4096)
```

```
    model.add(
        Conv2D(
            nb_filters_1, filter_size_1,
            filter_size_1, subsample=stride_1,
            input_shape=(patch_size, patch_size, num_channels), kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size_1))
    model.add(
        Conv2D(
            nb_filters_2, filter_size_2,
            filter_size_2, subsample=stride_2, activation='relu'))
    #model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(
        Conv2D(
            nb_filters_3, filter_size_3,
            filter_size_3, subsample=stride_3, activation='relu'))
    #model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
```

I have browsed through all related question but none solved my issue. Please, help.

Comment: When you call model.fit, you're passing an array of shape (16210, 4096) for y, when it should be (None, 256) according to your model.

Comment: The same codes worked when I changed the number of units in the last layer to 4096. Any suggestion on why this happens? I looked up [keras documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#examples). I followed the same guidelines for the shape of the input and everything looks good but I still haven't figured out what exactly I did wrong

Comment: I checked the shape of X and y: `Shape of X: (16210, 64, 64, 3), Shape of y: (16210, 4096)` .This is what I fed into `model.fit(X, y, epochs=nb_epoch, callbacks=callbacks, validation_split=0.25)`.

Comment: The second dimension of y needs to match the output dimension of the last Dense layer. That's why it works when you change the units of the last layer to 4096.