# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (500,) [Sentiment Analysis]

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras, sentiment-analysis

Research done before asking this question:
[Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (None, 256) but got array with shape (16210, 4096)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47873374/error-when-checking-target-expected-dense-2-to-have-shape-none-256-but-got-a)

[ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (10000, 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623436/valueerror-error-when-checking-target-expected-dense-2-to-have-3-dimensions-b)

[Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51755160/error-when-checking-target-expected-dense-3-to-have-shape-2-but-got-array-wi)

I have searched for a solution to this problem for days now. Please help me figure this out.

```
vocab_size = 5000
dim = 32 
input_length_var = 500
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, dim, input_length=input_length_var)) 
model.add(LSTM(100)) 
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']) 
print(model.summary())
```

The above code is my model. I will now print the summary of above model:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 500, 1)            500
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 100)               40800
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 101
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 2
=================================================================
Total params: 41,403
Trainable params: 41,403
Non-trainable params: 0
```

And finally I will show you the result of np.shape():

```
(1117228, 500)
(1117228, 500)
```

I have tried everything from Reshape() to adding input_shape to the dense layers but the result is always the same. What am I doing wrong and how to I fix this? My task is sentiment analysis.

EDIT: I was told that the dimensions of output needed to be (1117228,1) and I needed sentiment scores in train_test_split for the labels. The first half of my csv is negative sentiment and the other half is positive sentiment. How would I use this?

Comment: in `embedding layer`, can you define it like giving input like this : `Embedding(vocab_size, dim, input_length)`

Comment: I have done this now.

Comment: Where do you get this error? Can you show the code which errors out and the full stack trace of the error?